# scala: define default parameters in a function (val) vs using a method (def)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following method:

```
scala> def method_with_default(x: String = "default") = {x + "!"}
method_with_default: (x: String)java.lang.String

scala> method_with_default()
res5: java.lang.String = default!

scala> method_with_default("value")
res6: java.lang.String = value!
```

I'm trying to achieve the same with a val, but I get a syntax error, like this:

(with no default value, this one compiles ok)

```
scala> val function_with_default = (x: String) => {x + "!"}
function_with_default: String => java.lang.String = <function1>
```

(but I couldn't get this one to compile...)

```
scala> val function_with_default = (x: String = "default") => {x + "!"}
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '=' found.
       val function_with_default = (x: String = "default") => {x + "!"}
                                              ^
```

any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to do this. The best you can get is an object that extends both `Function1` and `Function0` where the apply method of `Function0` calls the other apply method with the default parameter.

```
val functionWithDefault = new Function1[String,String] with Function0[String] {
  override def apply = apply("default")
  override def apply(x:String) = x + "!"
}
```

If you need such functions more often, you can factor out the default apply method into an abstract class `DefaultFunction1` like this:

```
val functionWithDefault = new DefaultFunction1[String,String]("default") {
  override def apply(x:String) = x + "!"
}

abstract class DefaultFunction1[-A,+B](default:A)
               extends Function1[A,B] with Function0[B] {
  override def apply = apply(default)
}
```

Comment: Function1 with Function0 is quite clever, but I'd say it's a bit smelly. Only my opinion here. No discussion intended. :)

Comment: BTW you can use the sugars for functions: `new (String => String) with (() => String) { override def apply = apply("default"); override def apply(x:String) = x + "!" }` works.

Comment: I agree it's a bit smelly, but I don't see a solution that isn't.

Comment: I'd rework the problem to: don't do that :) and use idiomatic Scala. Still, your solution could be made generic with some clever usage of currying and implicit conversions.

Comment: Is there any reason why this is not supported by Scala? it would make things more coherent and simple